# How to prove if two functions $f$ and $g$ are strictly increasing then their composite $g(f(x))$ is strictly increasing.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I'm trying to figure out how to structure this proof. I began by stating the definition of increasing functions and saying that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ and $g(x_1)>g(x_2)$, but I'm unsure as to where to go from there to get a conclusion for the composition. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Write out fully what you need to prove:  $x_1 <x_2 \Rightarrow g(f(x_1)) < g(f(x_2))$.  Do you see how to get there using that BOTH $f$ and $g$ are increasing?

Comment: I'm really not understanding how to connect the two. I got to the point saying g(x1)>g(x2), but im not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You do not want to prove that $g(x_1) > g(x_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x<y$. Then since $f$ is increasing, $f(x)<f(y)$.

Now repeat that starting with $f(x)<f(y)$ and the fact that $g$ is increasing.